# Win XP very slow booting up - multiple volume files?

Tags: windows, audio

Windows XP Home Premium with SP3
500MB RAM
2.9 GHz Processor
50GB free space on HD

My sister's PC takes ages to boot up so she asked me to look at it...

Upon inspection within task manager it appears that about 40 instances of the volume control seem to be open in the task manager applications tab?  These subsequently correspond to about 40 sndvol32.exe processes in the processes tab.

So this would seem to be why her computer takes ages to start but why these volume files are appearing so much i do not know?

Any ideas/thoughts appreciated?

Comment: Any particular reason why this is community-wiki?

Comment: Erm no none whatsoever i have unticked the community Wiki checkbox for all future posts - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get [**Autoruns**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and clean up the startup routine then.

also have a look at [Blackviper's service tweak guide](http://www.blackviper.com/WinXP/servicecfg.htm).

Comment: Thanks - Autoruns works nicely and my sister is now happy again

Comment: you're most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If I start `sndvol32.exe` before the system has fully started, I find I get multiple instances of it running.

If it's in startup, take it out.

If you want to get rid of the `sndvol32.exe` processes, run

```
taskkill /f /im sndvol32.exe
```

from Start → Run, or a command prompt.